# SSL connection error while updating MikTex

Tags: miktex

I was unable to update my packages as the error "SSL Connection error". Can you please give me suggestion to solve this issue.

I am hereby providing the log file for your information.
Thanks in Advance,
Maharshi

```
2016-12-06 20:03:24,230+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-06 20:03:54,669+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-06 20:03:54,669+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-06 20:04:05,399+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-06 20:04:15,465+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-06 20:04:15,465+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-06 20:04:36,036+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-06 20:04:50,173+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-06 20:04:50,173+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 09:13:32,024+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 09:14:30,115+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 09:14:30,115+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: Couldn't resolve host name
2016-12-07 09:14:49,407+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 09:15:18,786+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 09:15:18,786+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 09:17:59,666+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 09:18:12,852+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 09:18:12,852+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 09:24:44,601+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 09:24:58,359+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 09:24:58,359+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 09:31:51,506+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 09:32:10,343+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 09:32:10,343+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 09:34:00,195+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 11:07:53,217+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 11:08:10,323+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 11:08:10,323+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 12:59:43,958+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 12:59:56,847+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 12:59:56,847+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 13:02:58,123+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 13:03:06,133+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 13:03:06,133+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 14:25:08,148+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 14:25:19,987+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 14:25:19,987+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2016-12-07 14:53:37,066+0530 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-07 14:53:48,879+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2016-12-07 14:53:48,879+0530 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
```

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2548/

Comment: In my default browser got a overall rating B, with 100 % in certificates, protocol support - 100%, key exchange - 70%, cipher strength - 90%; What can I modify now, can you please suggest.

Comment: I have no idea. It works fine on my machine. so I did't really follow the discussion. It **sounds** as if a IE on the PC could cause problems (if if you don't use it), and it **sounds** as if you can get around the problem by setting the environment variable as suggest by Christian.

Comment: I just switched to TexLive and its working good. Thanks for your help @Ulrike Fischer.

Comment: Any solution other than reinstalling the operating system or quitting using MiKTeX?